# generating debug info with emscripten / ninja / cmake on complex project

Tags: cmake, webassembly, emscripten

I am trying to debug a port of some c and c++ code to WASM. I worked out how to source level debug in the browser with a simple 10 line .c program but now I want to make that work with a non trivial code base. (mixed c and c++). The wasm code works in a simple app but not in my more complex use case, hence the need to debug it

I use CMake to generate ninja build files

Here is where I am setting flags in my CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} \
  -s MODULARIZE=1 \
  -s SINGLE_FILE=1 \
  -s EXPORT_NAME=aubio \
  -g --bind")
```

this was basically copied from the original codebase (the -g instead of -Oz is mine), I am not a CMake nor ninja nor emscripten wizard. When I build this I can see that the CXX flags are not passed to the emc++ compile passes, only to the 'linker' phase

I am not even sure where the -g (perhaps with source-map) needs to be for a multi-file project 'linked' into a single file. Should it be on the compile passes or the link pass , or maybe both. But certainly at the moment I do not get any symbols anywhere, no 'map' file(s) (embedded DWARF?, since the browser plugin claims to support it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

seems to embed DWARF to WASM file.

I don't know why `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g")` nor `target_compile_options(foo PUBLIC -g)` doesn't work in Release build.

Comment: Will check this out once I get back home to my dev system next week. Ty

Comment: i tried this out, it builds and says stuff about dwarf, but nothing i can do will persude chrome to do source level debugging. I have installed the extension that i used before, but that was using source maps.

Comment: I needed to check "WebAssembly Debugging: Enable DWARF support" and to install C/C++ DevTools Support (DWARF) extension. https://developer.chrome.com/blog/wasm-debugging-2020/

Comment: bingo, take your bonus